# How can I refresh SpringSecurityConfig using Observer pattern?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to implement a way to change the security credentials for a Spring boot app without needing to restart the server. By "security credentials", I mean a list of username and password combinations to restrict access to the app.

Using observer pattern, how would I be able to refresh this configuration file, if that's even possible?

I'm sharing the skeleton of my code only due to NDA restrictions:

```java
// ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // http configuration code here...
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //set up credentials here
        //...
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(username).password(password)
                .roles(AUTH_USER_ROLE);
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO force a refresh of this configuration
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "security credentials"?

Comment: Maybe you need to define custom `AuthenticationProvider` and set it `auth.authenticationProvider(provider);`. `inMemoryAuthentication` is designed to be `readonly` security provider

Comment: @Valijon I will give it a shot.